# How can i Change Cookie Name in OPENAM

Tags: java, cookies, single-sign-on, openam

I am using cookies in my application but the problem is OPENAM has it's own default cookie name which is iPlanetDirectoryPro and i am not able to change that name. I know the location that where to change but when i just change and save the goes to inheritance setting page it is not changed yet.
Can someone help me out in this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the setting in the 'default server settings' as changing such a critical value should be applied to all OpenAM instances which share the same configuration.